# Bottom transparent shadow effect for ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, shadow

I want to add shadow effect to my ImageView, like a transparent from bottom side. Here two images  [with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zOIA.png)  and [without](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8u7U.png) shadow effect. Has any possible ways to make like this? Or is it better to take shadow svg file from the internet and put on the original imageView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your image in the same space with a gradient image using a `RelativeLayot` like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/your_image"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/grad"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The "grad" image is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="#181818"
        android:startColor="#00000000 " />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you so much. I guess it is.